# IE doesn't display tab with link on facebook page

Tags: html, css, facebook

I created 3 clickable buttons, one for facebook one for twitter and RSS. When I am putting link to my page on facebook IE stop display it, I see just small square with x inside. The other buttons work properly.

```
 <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ImmersiveIntegratedTechnologies"><img src="Images/Facebooktab.jpg"></a></li>
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Are the facebook, Twitter and RSS images?

Comment: They look like this: http://i70.photobucket.com/albums/i115/iilasttochkaii/bb.jpg

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the images correctly?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Besides in other browsers all work good.

Comment: Live example please, otherwise this is not reproducible for anyone.

Comment: O, I fixed it already. The problem was that my image of facebook tab was saved like jpeg and IE refused to show it, so I change it to png and now everything work.